# MySQL Errors, Setting up first db (phpmyadmin, linux server)

Tags: php, mysql, database, linux, phpmyadmin

```
create user 'kai'@'%' identified by password 'mypass'
grant all privileges on *.* to 'kai'@'%' with grant option;  

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grant all privileges on *.* to 'kai'@'%' with grant option' at line 1
```

that's one example

I've tried several different ways including @%, @localhost, etc. My database's name is eve and my site is sdnam.net. I tried asking a friend and he said he has cpanel/phpmyadmin in place. I tried setting up phpmyadmin, but it made things more of a headache so I took a step back. i tried going through the mysql guide they have in place, but it didn't help too much. I considered maybe I needed to use @192., etc, but I don't think that'd be secure.

Any pointers would be excellent, I'm sure I'm just skipping something easy and I don't know the proper terminology to google or I would have found it already ;). This is on Debian 7 64bit, dunno how important that is but everything is updated, etc.

Cheers

Edit: Code above, I've been following this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

and read through
[ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db)

Answer (score 0):

`priveleges` is spelt incorrectly (it should be `privileges`).

**UPDATE** Also, I think you're trying to do two things at once?  `create user 'kai'@'%' identified by password 'mypass' grant all priveleges on eve.* to 'kai'@'%' with grant option;` is at least two commands.. there should probably be a delimiter after `password 'mypass'`?

Comment: Sigh, I keep doing that, I've fixed that mistake before, but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
create user 'kai'@'%' identified by password 'mypass' ; <---// you missed semicolon here
grant all privileges on *.* to 'kai'@'%' with grant option;
```

check this

[Correct mysql syntax error when creating a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394005/correct-mysql-syntax-error-when-creating-a-user)

Comment: those were two separate queries, I shouldn't have posted without proofreading sorry.

Comment: Should I be using localhost? My IP? sdnam.net?
Edit: back to error 1396
    create user 'kai'@'%' identified by password 'mypass';
    ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'kai'@'%'